# Gnome's "scale" feature breaks UI of Settings and Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, scale-mode

Ubuntu 20.04.
When I set the scaling factor to 125% (or any others), in Settings the "Network" icon on the sidebar becomes huge:
[image]

And the sidebar icons of the file manager (Nautilus) do not show properly, either.
[image]

These are all the inconsistencies that I've found so far.
Is it a bug of Gnome, or I can configure it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to the default icon theme. Does the issue reproduce then? If not, then the the problem is with the icon theme you use. You then may want to raise the issue to the developpers of the theme.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, and it was indeed the icon theme's problem. Thank you <3